# Getting the sides of unit circle

Tags: trigonometry

Im very confused on how to get the sides of the unit circle. By that i mean like sin/cos of 0,90,180,360... I can get the others by this logic for example:

Image:
[image]

For example if it asks me

1. Sin 150: I would first see the quadrant.. Its Quadrant II so it
   means Sin is the only one positive... Ok so i know its positive, and
   next i would know that sin is always the hieght so according to that
   picture it is 1/2.. So i would know the sin of 150 is 1/2...

I can do that for every angle presented on the picture exept the 0,90,180,360... How do you possible calculate the sin/cos for the angles i just mentioned. Thankyou

Comment: The only way out of it i can guess is memorizing the pattern....??? @LuizCordeiro

Comment: Im not memorizing all... Im just memorizing 0,90,180,360.... the others are easy to figure out.. And its just a pattern.. For cos in 0-360 it goes 1,0,-1,1  For sin 0,1,0,0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following triangles, use the Pythagorean theorem to find the missing lengths, then find the trigonometric ratios for $0,\pi/2, \pi/3,\pi/4,$ and $\pi/6$. Don't even bother memorizing, just draw the appropriate triangle.

[image]

Comment: What do you need the degenerated triangle for?

Comment: @Surb The degenerated triangle is for calculating $\sin 0$ and $\sin\pi/2$ ala opposite-adjacent-hypotenuse style.

Comment: Dosent really matter know since i memorized pattern lol. But thanks for helpin me out