# Why is cos at $\pi/2$ not undefined?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, definition

If the $\cos$ function is based off of the ratio of the adjacent side of Euclidean, **right** triangle, with fixed hypotenuse length (such as the unit circle), then how does this correspond to a defined value when $\theta = \pi/2$ ? To me the limit as $\theta \rightarrow 90$ appears to be undefined (specifically 1/0).

Arguments against my view point:
1.) Once you hit 90 for a triangle to exist a new, right triangle will be formed, that is if the hypotenuse is a real number. **Counterpoint**: That's not the same angle, $\theta$, we used for our original function and when you hit 90 there's not going to be an adjacent side length of zero.

Comment: This is a pretty good question. I would say that you are correct about there being a problem (you don't have a triangle), however you can extend it continuously to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: The triangle definition of the trig functions are only valid for $\theta$ in $(0,\pi/2)$.  Luckily that's not the only definition we have.

Comment: The sine and cosine functions can be defined in terms of projections of a hypotenuse (or radius or other fixed length) onto the $  \ x- $ and $  \ y-$ axes, which are never undefined.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner I think they just mixed up which order the ratio goes in.

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/145828/409) may be helpful.

Comment: $\cos$ is defined rigorously using power series.

Comment: Like Cameron said, the limit is $0/1$, not $1/0$.

Comment: See this answer for a representation of a perpendicular right triangle. http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1678623/140156

Comment: Yeah the limit is 0/1. But the cosine function is continuous and does not exist at $\pi/2$ (in sole terms of triangles ratios). It's strange that this function is defined by it's power series like Henry said, because didn't these functions and their cartesian graphs exist before power series existed?